# Console application to print AD and TFS Groups of Specific user by inputing username and collection url

Tags: c#, tfs

```
namespace TFSGroupMembersFast
{
    class Program
    {
        static Dictionary<IdentityDescriptor, TeamFoundationIdentity> 
        m_identities =
        new Dictionary<IdentityDescriptor, TeamFoundationIdentity> 
        (IdentityDescriptorComparer.Instance);
        static List<TeamFoundationIdentity> m_groups = new 
        List<TeamFoundationIdentity>();
        static string uname;
        static IIdentityManagementService _ims;
        static List<string> grname = new List<string>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter TFS server or project collection Url");
            Console.Write("e.g. http://localhost:8080/tfs/defaultcollection: ");
            Console.WriteLine();
            string address = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Team Project Uri for project scope, else 
            empty string");
            Console.Write("e.g. vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/****: ");
            string projectUri = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter user name:");
            uname = Console.ReadLine();

            DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

            TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(TfsTeamProjectCollection.GetFullyQualifiedUriForName(address));
            _ims = tfs.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(projectUri))
            {
                TeamFoundationIdentity group = 
                _ims.ReadIdentity(GroupWellKnownDescriptors.EveryoneGroup, 
                MembershipQuery.Direct, ReadIdentityOptions.None);
                m_identities[group.Descriptor] = group;
                m_groups.Add(group);

                // Get expanded membership of the Valid Users group, which is all 
                identities in this host             
                group = 
                _ims.ReadIdentity(GroupWellKnownDescriptors.EveryoneGroup, 
                MembershipQuery.Expanded, ReadIdentityOptions.None);
                FetchIdentities(group.Members);
            }
            else
            {
                // Get all groups in this project
                TeamFoundationIdentity[] projectGroups = 
                _ims.ListApplicationGroups(projectUri, ReadIdentityOptions.None);

                Dictionary<IdentityDescriptor, object> descSet = new Dictionary<IdentityDescriptor, object>(IdentityDescriptorComparer.Instance);

                foreach (TeamFoundationIdentity projectGroup in projectGroups)
                {
                    descSet[projectGroup.Descriptor] = projectGroup.Descriptor;
                }

                // Expanded membership of project groups
                projectGroups = _ims.ReadIdentities(descSet.Keys.ToArray(), 
                MembershipQuery.Expanded, ReadIdentityOptions.None);

                // Collect all descriptors
                foreach (TeamFoundationIdentity projectGroup in projectGroups)
                {
                    foreach (IdentityDescriptor mem in projectGroup.Members)
                    {
                        descSet[mem] = mem;
                    }
                }

                FetchIdentities(descSet.Keys.ToArray());
            }

            // Now output groups and their members.
            foreach (TeamFoundationIdentity identity in m_groups)
            {
                Write(identity);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("======= Finished reading {0} 
            identities in {1} minutes",
                m_identities.Count, (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalMinutes));

            for (int i = 0; i < grname.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(grname[i]);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void FetchIdentities(IdentityDescriptor[] descriptors)
        {
            TeamFoundationIdentity[] identities;

            // If total membership exceeds batch size limit for Read, break it up
            int batchSizeLimit = 100000;

            if (descriptors.Length > batchSizeLimit)
            {
                int batchNum = 0;
                int remainder = descriptors.Length;
                IdentityDescriptor[] batchDescriptors = new 
                IdentityDescriptor[batchSizeLimit];

                while (remainder > 0)
                {
                    int startAt = batchNum * batchSizeLimit;
                    int length = batchSizeLimit;
                    if (length > remainder)
                    {
                        length = remainder;
                        batchDescriptors = new IdentityDescriptor[length];
                    }

                    Array.Copy(descriptors, startAt, batchDescriptors, 0,length);
                    identities = _ims.ReadIdentities(batchDescriptors, 
                    MembershipQuery.Direct, ReadIdentityOptions.None);
                    SortIdentities(identities);
                    remainder -= length;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                identities = _ims.ReadIdentities(descriptors, 
                MembershipQuery.Direct, ReadIdentityOptions.None);
                SortIdentities(identities);
            }
        }

        static void SortIdentities(TeamFoundationIdentity[] identities)
        {
            foreach (TeamFoundationIdentity identity in identities)
            {
                m_identities[identity.Descriptor] = identity;

                if (identity.IsContainer)
                {
                    m_groups.Add(identity);
                }
            }
        }

        static void Write(TeamFoundationIdentity group)
        {
            // Output this group's membership
            Console.WriteLine("Members of group: {0}", group.DisplayName);
            Console.WriteLine("=================");

            foreach (IdentityDescriptor memDesc in group.Members)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m_identities[memDesc].DisplayName);
                if (m_identities[memDesc].DisplayName == uname)
                {
                    grname.Add(group.DisplayName);

                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I  got the groups the user belong but i want to differentiate the groups as AD Group and TFS Group

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, in TFS the AD groups will map to TFS Group first, So no elements to differentiate the groups as AD Group and TFS Group

However we can differentiate the users as local or domain user:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GetUser
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));
            tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();

            IGroupSecurityService gss = tfs.GetService<IGroupSecurityService>();

            Identity SIDS = gss.ReadIdentity(SearchFactor.AccountName, "Project Collection Valid Users", QueryMembership.Expanded);

            Identity[] UserId = gss.ReadIdentities(SearchFactor.Sid, SIDS.Members, QueryMembership.Direct);

            foreach (Identity user in UserId)
            {
                if (user != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(user.AccountName);
                    Console.WriteLine(user.Domain);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @MachineAS Have you resolved the issue by the answer? any update?